# Apache hive: how to get data type of expression? Is there some analogs of Spark typeof or PostgresSQL pg_typeof functions?

Tags: apache-spark, hive

There are functions [typeof](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.typeof.html) in Apache Spark and [pg_typeof](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-info.html) in PostgreSQL to get data type of any value or expression like

```
select typeof(1=1)

╭───────────────────╮
│ typeof((1 = 1))   │
├───────────────────┤
│ boolean           │
╰───────────────────╯
```

Is there similar function in Apache Hive?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to gather a way through which this can be gradually achieved:

The documentation of Hive suggests the [java_method](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) UDF which can be used to run a Java class on hive to get the result. This is a generic UDF which invokes the [GenericUDFReflect](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDFReflect.java#L47C14-L47C31) class to run the Java method with the arguments passed in the Hive query.

The method signature: `java_method(class, method[, arg1[, arg2..]])` can be converted to the following

```sql
SELECT java_method('java.lang.Object', 'getClass', (1==1));
```

to get the Java type of the expression you are passing as an argument. In this case it should return `java.lang.Boolean` as the result, which is the Java class for a boolean value.

Another alternate is to use the `reflect` method in Hive to get the same result:

```sql
SELECT reflect((1==1), 'getClass');
```

Comment: Unfortunately as is it does not work :( `SELECT reflect((1==1), 'getClass')` `Argument type mismatch '1': The first 2 parameters of GenericUDFReflect(class,method[,arg1[,arg2]...]) should be string.`, but i'll dig in this direction, thank you.